# Expresión regular que valide uno o más bloques de texto que siguen un patrón, separados por ";"

Tags: c#, vb.net, regex

Estoy tratando de montar una expresión regular que me valide bloques de texto consecutivos. Cada bloque tiene en este orden, consecutivamente:

- Obligatorio una o más letras o números. Sólo pueden ser letras de a a z, de A a Z, o números de 0 a 9.
- Obligatorio un espacio
- Obligatorio un "de"
- Obligatorio un espacio
- Obligatorio al menos un número.
- Un ";". Si es el último bloque, puede omitirse (es opcional al final del texto)

He probado `^([a-zA-Z0-9]* de [0-9;]*)*$` pero no consigo que un segundo bloque igual después del ";" se valide correctamente.

Algunos valores válidos serían:

> - `AA123 de 123456;BB456 de 123456`
> - `AA123 de 123456;BB456 de 123456;`
> - `AA123 de 123456;`
> - `AA123 de 123456`

Además, he probado esta expresión

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+ de [0-9]+;*)*$
```

y parece que funciona. ¿Parece correcta o alguien ve algo mejorable?

Comment: ¿El `;` opcional es *siempre* opcional, o sólo se puede omitir en el último bloque? ¿Podrías agregar casos que no deberían coincidir, como se pide en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info?

Comment: Es opcional siempre. Si solo hay un elemento puede acabar con ";" o no. Es simplemente el separador para el split.

Comment: entonces `3 de 45 de 6` es válido, verdad?

Comment: No. Claro, me refiero a opcional en el caso de que solo exista un bloque. Si solo existe un bloque puede acabar o no por ";". Si hay mas de un bloque, deben estar separados por ";".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partiendo de tu expresión, yo usaría:

```
^(?>[a-zA-Z0-9]+ de [0-9]+;?)+$
```

- `^(?> )+$` - bloques de múltiples expresiones iguales.
- Estas expresiones son del tipo: `(?>[a-zA-Z0-9]+ de [0-9]+;?)`

  - `(?>X)` - este es un [grupo atómico](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) para prevenir el backtracking. Así, una vez la expresión `X` ha sido encontrada no intenta otras combinaciones de forma reiterativa provocando un estruendoso colapso ([como aquí](http://rextester.com/TOS71296)). Lee los comentarios de Mariano para mayor detalle.
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - letras y números
  - `de` - texto " de "
  - `[0-9]+` - al menos un número
  - `;?` - un punto y coma opcional

Básicamente, hago que `;` sea opcional utilizando el cuantificador `?`. Este implica que la expresión a su izquierda puede aparecer una o ninguna veces.

Además, cambié el `( )*` que pusiste alrededor por `(?> )+` para que al menos una ocurrencia se dé. En caso contrario, una línea en blanco pasaría el corte.

Pruébalo online en https://regex101.com/r/27ijuN/3

Esto permite que las siguientes parten el corte:

```
AA123 de 123456;
BB456 de 123456
AA123 de 123456;
BB456 de 123456;
AA123 de 123456;
AA123 de 123456
AA123 de 123456;BB456 de 123456
AA123 de 123456;BB456 de 123456;
```

Y que esta no:

```
AA123 de 123456;;
```

Así como tampoco la línea vacía

Que es la diferencia con tu expresión.

Comment: Sí, claro! Un grupo atómico previene el *backtracking*. Una vez que coincidió con  `(?>expr)`, no puede intentar otra alternativa de "`expr`"... De paso, para .net no conviene usar regex101 sino alguna de las listadas en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info (al menos para garantizar que sea compatible)